# PHP & SQL inserting into a database table error

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm slowly progressing through PHP and SQL and have stumbled upon a small error, when trying to send a string into an SQL database. What I'm trying to do is insert a users's detail into one table (which currently works) and send the user name along with 5 blank entries into another table. The table examscore fields are username, exam, exam1, exam2, exam3, exam4 (it is these exam fields that I require blank for now).

The problem is that I receive the following message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-LearningWebsite\addcustomertodb.php on line 11 (which line that starts $query1)

If possible could anyone explain what this error means and what i have done wrong?

```
<?php
require "dbconn.php";

$username = $_GET['username'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

$query = "INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('".$username."','".$email."','".$pass."')";

$query1 = "INSERT INTO examscores VALUES ('".$username."','""','""','""','""','""')";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$results1 = mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

Kind regards Andy

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely insecure and vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Although this question is important for you, it is way too localized for this site. Why not to use search first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO examscores VALUES ('".$username."','""','""','""','""','""')";
```

to

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO examscores VALUES ('".$username."','','','','','')";
```

ps. you are inviting SQL injections but that is a different story...

Comment: Thank you for your time, a little bit of extra knowledge gained. Much appreciated - Andy

Answer (score 2):

The goggles! They do nothing! The [sql injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com)! And it's only Monday!

Why not just

```
$query ="INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$pass');";
$query1 = "INSERT INTO examscores VALUES ('$username', '', '', '', etc...);";
```

PHP will happily replace $vars inside `""` quoted strings for you. There's absolutely not need for all the concatentation you're doing. Any decent code editor will still highlight the vars for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, a little bit of extra knowledge gained. Much appreciated - Andy

Answer (score 2):

you are missing dots to concatenate your strings

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO examscores VALUES ('".$username."','"."','"."','"."','"."','"."')";
```

furthermore you dont need to have different strings
and still further more you dont need to include every column if you are not inserting them

Comment: Thank you for your time, a little bit of extra knowledge gained. Much appreciated - Andy

Answer (score 1):

Your *immediate problem* causing the errors is the missing `.`s from query1 from between the double-doublequotes,  (or you should just delete the double-doublequotes altogether. Or even the unneeded columns...).

But there are **way bigger issues** in your code:

- **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**: your code is vulnerable. You should at least escape th variables coming from the user...
- **[mysql_* deprecation](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799)**: as of PHP 5.5, these functions will be deprecated. Use either Mysqli or even ebtter PDO.

Comment: Thank you for your time, a little bit of extra knowledge gained. Much appreciated - Andy